# How to dump MySQL's edit log?

Tags: mysql

I want to dump edit logs of a MySQL table into an external file, where we can see the records that were inserted, updated and deleted. I remember we can implement such a feature in MySQL, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: See this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html

Comment: Besides, I'd like to know whether we can do time-based incremental data dumping, i.e., dumping data that were inserted during a specified time range, if there is no timestamp related column in a table ?